# Combobox disappears in WPF when using a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, combobox

I'm designing a UI in XAML in a WPF project, but when I add a Combobox to my Canvas, my Combobox disappears. I tried removing the canvas, but then I can only add 1 item to it since content will be used more than once.

My code:

```
<TabItem Header ="Ordering">
    <Canvas>
        <ComboBox x:Name="CB_Workers_Naam" Height="60" Width="100" Margin="507,-300,47,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="100" Width="75"/>
    </Canvas>
</TabItem>
```

Any help is welcome, and have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another Panel controle, such as Grid control:

```
<TabItem Header ="Ordering">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="CB_Workers_Naam" Height="60" Width="100" Margin="507,-300,47,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="100" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

the Canvas its a primitive panel, you must set the position of the children using explicit coordinates (Canvas.Top="150"). Example:

```
<TabItem Header ="Ordering">
    <Canvas>
        <ComboBox x:Name="CB_Workers_Naam" Height="60" Width="100" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" />
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="100" Width="75"  Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="60"/>
    </Canvas>
</TabItem>
```